Is it possible to reference one Desired State Configuration file within another?
I am in the process of setting up a repository, and I would like to use Desired State Configuration to help others setup their development environment. I would like to create a .dsc.yaml file for a development environment (IDE and other components), as well as a "subset" .dsc.yaml file for the runtime dependencies i.e. NodeJS.
I am wondering if it is possible to combine these files in some way, i.e. have one file that conditionally installs components depending on an environment variable, or have the development file reference the runtime file. I would like to avoid duplication.
I have not been able to find any documentation to support chaining, or conditions within DSC files.
YAML/JSON files do not support overrides, chaining or conditions on their own.
